# In visual studio, is there a preprocessor definition like _DEBUG for running release with debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, c-preprocessor

In Visual Studio, you can distinguish between Debug and Release modes using the _DEBUG definition. But even in release mode, you can either "Start Debugging" (F5) or "Start Without Debugging" (Ctrl + F5). Is there a preprocessor definition that distinguishes between these?

Comment: Debugging is a step after building. The system doesn't know at build time, which button the user is going to push it in the future. (What if the user does both?) Are you suggesting that pushing the debugging button should always force a rebuild, with a clue as to what the user is probably going to do next? That's not really how build configurations work.

Answer (score 0):

*Start Debugging* means *Start your program in the debugger*.

*Start Without Debugging* means *Start your program normally*.

Since you choose one of these actions *after* building the program (either in Debug or
Release), there cannot be any preprocessor macro or other compiletime difference
between the actions.

The Debug build of your program can be run in the debugger, and it can be run
normally. The Release build of your program can also be run in the debugger, or
normally. But if you run the Release build in the debugger, the debugger's
ability to present the program's internal state correctly, or at all, at any
given point may be hampered for lack of valid debugging information.

It appears what you want is be able to run a Release build effectively in the debugger.

There is nothing to stop you configuring your Release build to generate
debugging information like a Debug build: it's just not the default. See [How to: Debug a Release Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/reference/how-to-debug-a-release-build?view=vs-2017)

This would probably be a temporary measure. While debugging a Release build in this
way, the program flow you observe might at times appear unexpected, due to Release mode optimizations.